# Disable href on second consecutive click

Tags: javascript, list, anchor, href

I have a main menu with sub menus. When I clicked the sub menu, I want the href to be disabled on first click and then on second click enabled. If I click Sec Menu 1 and then click Sec Menu 2 - Sec Menu 1 should be disabled. It should only be enabled if it is clicked twice consecutively.

- [Secondary Menu 1](http://www.cnn.com)
- [Secondary Menu 2](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to `preventDefault()` for starters, and only allow the default action if link has been previously clicked. You can track that by adding an attribute and checking for its existence.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2ww0dfv/

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = handlerGen(i);
}

function handlerGen(index) {
    return function clickHandler(event) {
        var link = event.target;
        if (!link.hasAttribute('clicked')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            resetClicked(index);
        }
    };
}

function resetClicked(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (i == index) {
            links[i].setAttribute('clicked', true);
        } else {
            links[i].removeAttribute('clicked');
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using jquery, might want to use `.data()` instead.